# how to call method of Owner?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have `Class1`, which has methods:

1. `setSomething()`
2. `createObjectOfClass2()`

Now, when I create object of `Class2`, is it possible to call `setSomething` method from it?

Comment: -1 With a misleading title you frustrate everyone trying to answer, and yourself too.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

If you like, but you're introducing coupling, which will make separating functionality quite difficult later. Just make `setSomething` public and pass a reference to the first object to the second's constructor.

```
public class Class1 {
    Class2 object2 = null;

    public void setSomething(Object something) { ... }

    public void createObjectOfClass2() {
        object2 = new Class2(this);
    }
}

public class Class2 {
    public Class2(Class1 parent) {
        parent.setSomething(new Foo());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Class2(Class1 parent)` - very strange name for the parameter where Class2 is not inherited from Class1.

Comment: Roman: "parent" was in the original title, so I went with it. I think it fits: I personally don't like using "parent" as a pseudonym for "superclass". As you said in another comment though, "owner" fits too—feel free to change it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If Class2 doesn't extends Class1, then you can call setSomething() on any instance of Class1 if it's not a static method:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.setSomething();
```

Comment: Class2 doesn't seem to be a subclass of Class1.

Comment: I mystificated you by bad title. Class2 is not derived from class1.

Comment: @joseph: then edit it, `method of parent` has in mind that Class2 extends Class1

Answer (score 0):

Call Parent.this.method()

e.g.:

```
public class K1
{
public class K2
    {
    public void hello()
        {
        K1.this.setSomething();
        }

    } 

public void setSomething()
   {
   System.out.println("Set Something");
   }

public K2 createObjectOfClass2()
   {
   return new K2();
   }

public static void main(String args[])
   {
   new K1().createObjectOfClass2().hello();
   }


}
```

Comment: but I do not want create new instance, I need to call it from instance, that created the class2